# Not found actionIndex in my controller (Not Found (#404))

Tags: yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I get Not Found (#404) error by this url `http://localhost/chegda/backend/page/index`. But by this url `http://localhost/chegda/backend/page/index/` works

In additional I have to say, I use **the same** controller, model and view in another project, that there is **no** error such this.

Here is my controller:

```
<?php
namespace fcadmin\controllers;

use Yii;
use fcadmin\models\Page;
use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;

class PageController extends Controller
{

    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'delete' => ['POST'],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }

    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => Page::find(),
        ]);

        return $this->render('index', [
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);
    }
}
```

I really don't know what's the reason.

If it you need more detail ask it.

Comment: Is `fcadmin` a module? Is it added in configuration? What is the folder structure of this `index` view?

Comment: Your .htaccess file valid  and   'enablePrettyUrl' => true do you enable prettyUrl

Comment: @NuriddinRashidov I use fcadmin instead of backend. I mean I've changed name of backend folder to fcadmin. I edit my question now.

Comment: @NuriddinRashidov  I use the same .htaccess that I use in other project

Comment: check this url http://localhost/chegda/fcadmin/page/index

Comment: @NuriddinRashidov I use the same url

Comment: But you post this: http://localhost/chegda/backend/page/index

Comment: @NuriddinRashidov still there is that error

Comment: @NuriddinRashidov As I said I use this controller in another project, that it works on there

Comment: Which url mapping use resolve this url. Can you post this from debugger

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130589/discussion-between-mohammad-aghayari-and-nuriddin-rashidov).

Comment: @NuriddinRashidov Do you mean prettyUrl  in compnent? I use no url mapping

Comment: @NuriddinRashidov I have to add something else that found right now. this url `http://localhost/chegda/backend/page/index/` works.I mean I added `/` in the end.